# FFT Overlaps for feature extraction

Tags: fft

Fft question:
Do I need overlaps if I’m only grabbing some features like mel or bark? I don’t even necessarily need every frame of a STFT even one every second or so works. How I understand fft overlapping is that each overlap sums together after the final window after the inverse fft. However, for my needs I do not even do an inverse fft and I only extract mel and similar features in the frequency domain. So do I need to do overlapping for my use case? It doesn’t seem like the feature values i extract even consider the overlap.

Unless I’m supposed to combine overlapping fft values for the feature extraction itself??? Actually this makes me wonder if I should be doing that when extracting feature because some info is lost from the windowing to prevent spectral leaking. If that’s the case then do I just sum the window overlaps together after the fft and before feature extraction??

Because I don’t do that for spectral audio processing (again, i only sum after the final window after the ifft..) Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Welcome here! It's not clear to me what kind of features you're specifically trying to extract. Can you give me a definite list? and if you can, then these features are probably well-defined, and you need to do exactly what the (literature/wikipedia) definition says

Comment: Thanks. That’s a good suggestion! I am extracting mel, bark, melcc, maybe a couple others I’m not decided fully. I think I will do an overlap , my main question now is if I sum the overlap immediately after the fft since I’m not doing an ifft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way of doing an STFT is probably using a 50% overlap. The reason for this is quite simple: this roughly gives "equal" weight to all time domain samples and you are not missing anything important. Let's consider a signal that consists mainly out of a short large impulse: if you don't overlap you will get VERY different results depending how the impulse lines up with the window boundary.

If you signal is reasonably steady state and/or if the features you want to extract are not particularly sensitive to impulsive signals you can indeed do with less frames. However that depends a LOT on the property of your specific signals and the requirements of your application.

FWIW: Personally, I'm not a fan of not overlapping. Most "normal" audio signals do have prominent features that can be quite short and the incremental work of processing all samples using a 50% overlap seems minimal (for most applications).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was thinking the same thing after asking. I guess my question now is when/how to correctly sum the overlaps for the feature analysis? Because usually when I do spectral processing it is on real time audio and I sum the overlaps after the window following the inverse fft. Since I am not doing an ifft and just getting features, would I sum the overlaps immediately after the fft before the feature analysis? Thanks!!